# I want to remove duplicates from array of array of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to remove duplicates from an array of objects can anyone help with this to remove duplicates in the array of objects. I have an array of array of objects that I want to remove duplicates and I want to use

```
const firstArray = [
  {
    first: "01",
    data: [
      { id: "01", name: "test1" },
      { id: "02", name: "test2" },
      { id: "03", name: "test3" },
      { id: "05", name: "test1" },
      { id: "06", name: "test2" },
      { id: "07", name: "test1" }
    ]
  },
  {
    first: "02",
    data: [
      { id: "01", name: "test2" },
      { id: "02", name: "test1" },
      { id: "03", name: "test3" },
      { id: "05", name: "test2" },
      { id: "06", name: "test2" },
      { id: "07", name: "test1" }
    ]
  },
  {
    first: "03",
    data: [
      { id: "01", name: "test3" },
      { id: "02", name: "test2" },
      { id: "03", name: "test3" },
      { id: "04", name: "test2" },
      { id: "05", name: "test3" },
      { id: "07", name: "test1" }
    ]
  }
];
```

this is the sample result code i am expecting :

````
const firstArray = [
  {
    first: "01",
    data: [
      { id: "01", name: "test1" },
      { id: "02", name: "test2" },
      { id: "03", name: "test3" },
    ]
  },
  {
    first: "02",
    data: [
      { id: "01", name: "test1" },
      { id: "02", name: "test2" },
      { id: "03", name: "test3" },
    ]
  },
  {
    first: "03",
    data: [
      { id: "05", name: "test1" },
      { id: "06", name: "test2" },
      { id: "07", name: "test3" }
    ]
  }
];```
````

Comment: May you share an attempt of your own, and the expected output?

Comment: Duplicates at what level? Show your expected result.

Comment: And the expected output is.......?

Comment: I have given sample expected code

Comment: As soon as the OP does specify the definition of  *duplicate* (here most probably any equal  `name` value of a `data` item within each separate `data` array), the OP him/herself might get more clear about an own approach. The most important information for any approach of cause was whether one wants another array as result or one wants to mutate the original(ly provided) array reference (here `firstArray`).

Comment: you saying that we cannot remove remote duplicates from the firstArray..?

Comment: no, they all say your question is fuzzy because you haven't given any definition of what you call a duplicate (the criteria)

Comment: for example why are the `data` arrays of `first: '02'` and `first: '03'` are not empty when all their elements have the same value as those of `first: '01'` ?

Comment: @ManoharPamishetty ... in case *"you saying that we cannot remove remote duplicates from the firstArray"* was asked into my direction ...  one already could choose from two distinct approaches. One which (directly) mutates `firstArray`, and where I would choose the array methods `reduce`, `findIndex` (or a lookup table) and `splice`. One also could return a new array without any duplicates, where I would choose  `reduce` or `map` and `filter` and `includes` (or a lookup table).

Comment: the duplicates are available in the data Array, that's y i said duplicates,

Answer (score 1):

this way..

```js
const firstArray = 
    [ { first: '01'
      , data: 
        [ { id: '01', name: 'test1' } 
        , { id: '02', name: 'test2' } 
        , { id: '03', name: 'test3' } 
        , { id: '05', name: 'test1' } 
        , { id: '06', name: 'test2' } 
        , { id: '07', name: 'test1' } 
      ] } 
    , { first: '02'
      , data: 
        [ { id: '01', name: 'test2' } 
        , { id: '02', name: 'test1' } 
        , { id: '03', name: 'test3' } 
        , { id: '05', name: 'test2' } 
        , { id: '06', name: 'test2' } 
        , { id: '07', name: 'test1' } 
      ] } 
    , { first: '03'
      , data: 
        [ { id: '01', name: 'test3' } 
        , { id: '02', name: 'test2' } 
        , { id: '03', name: 'test3' } 
        , { id: '04', name: 'test2' } 
        , { id: '05', name: 'test3' } 
        , { id: '07', name: 'test1' } 
    ] } ] 
  
firstArray.forEach(({data})=> 
  {
  for (let i=data.length;--i>0;) 
  if (data.findIndex(({name})=>name===data[i].name) < i)
    data.splice(i,1)
  })


console.log( JSON.stringify( firstArray,0,2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Comment: hi @Mister, i want to enter the value to filter , can i use like this ```data.findIndex(({name})=>name=== "test1", ```

Comment: everything is doable but i don't understand what i'm asking: filter elements on a key or eliminate all duplicates?

Comment: thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

```js
const firstArray = [
    {
      first: "01",
      data: [
        { id: "01", name: "test1" },
        { id: "02", name: "test2" },
        { id: "03", name: "test3" },
        { id: "05", name: "test1" },
        { id: "06", name: "test2" },
        { id: "07", name: "test1" }
      ]
    },
    {
      first: "02",
      data: [
        { id: "01", name: "test2" },
        { id: "02", name: "test1" },
        { id: "03", name: "test3" },
        { id: "05", name: "test2" },
        { id: "06", name: "test2" },
        { id: "07", name: "test1" }
      ]
    },
    {
      first: "03",
      data: [
        { id: "01", name: "test3" },
        { id: "02", name: "test2" },
        { id: "03", name: "test3" },
        { id: "04", name: "test2" },
        { id: "05", name: "test3" },
        { id: "07", name: "test1" }
      ]
    }
  ];


let filterValues = firstArray.map((item) => {
  let data = item.data.filter(
    (value, index, data) =>
      data.findIndex((item) => item.name === value.name) === index
  );
  return { ...{ first: item.first }, data };
});

console.log(filterValues);
```